# Restore from SQL Server database and replicate to another database

Tags: sql-server, backup, replication

We have a SQL Server database that is hosted by a 3rd party. We have access to the backup files of that SQL Server database which we grab daily and restore to an "in-house" SQL Server for the purpose of creating reports and looking at the data without the chance of affecting the "live" data on the hosted server.

At the moment our restore process only allows us to access day old data, but we would like to increase the frequency of backup/restore processes so our "sandbox" database is more up to date, like maybe 2 or 3 hours old. One issue is that during the restore process everyone has to be out of the database so restoring every couple of hours might be cumbersome.

Is it possible to setup a 3rd SQL Server for the "sandbox" database to replicate to so that when we restore the data to it, that data will then replicate to the "user" database.

Is there a better way to get the data from the actual production server?

Comment: Sure, but instead of restoring the FULL backup each time, I would ask for [LOG backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) or just enable log-shipping. Then you wouldn't even need the lengthy downtime since you can restore logs pretty quickly (depending on their size, thus request them frequently) and you could even RESTORE WITH STANDBY so it's readable. This would mean you wouldn't need the third server at all.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use replication?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Brian mentions another feasible option, but most people cringe a bit at the sound of replication.